# Reusable View Groups

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewgroup

Most of the pages in my application have a progress bar implementation. 
I would like to create a custom view group which always includes a progress bar.

For example,

```
<LinearLayout ...>
<ProgressBar .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can I create something like

```
<ActivityBody...>
//Other elements
</ActivityBody>
```

Where activity body always has the ProgressBar so I can always just hide and show progress bar as needed without including the progress bar each time.

Comment: sure, provided `ActivityBody` is a `ViewGroup` (custom `LinearLayout` for example)

Comment: yes, but an example to illustrate how i would add the progress bar to the ActivityBody will be great.

Comment: just call `addView()`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 1):

create new custom ViewGroup extends **FrameLayout**

like this :

```
public class CustomLayout extends FrameLayout {
    ProgressBar myProgressBar;
    public CustomLayout (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void show() {
        if (myProgressBar == null) {
            addMyProgressBar();
        }
        myProgressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hide() {
        if (myProgressBar == null) {
            addMyProgressBar();
        }
        myProgressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    private void addMyProgressBar() {
        myProgressBar = new ProgressBar(getContext());
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(100, 100, Gravity.CENTER);
        addView(myProgressBar, params);
    }
}
```

if you want to make ProgressBar always on Top:

- edit `show()`, and `hide()` methods.
- add `removeMyProgressBar()` method.

to be like this :

```
public void show() {
    if (myProgressBar == null)
        addMyProgressBar();
}

public void hide() {
    if (myProgressBar != null)
        removeMyProgressBar();
}

private void removeMyProgressBar() {
    if (myProgressBar != null) {
        removeView(myProgressBar);
        myProgressBar = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer. I followed the steps here and modified them for my own purposes and it was the perfect guide to solving my problem.